# Using variable as a part of a pattern in preg_match not working for spacial characters

Tags: php

I have a string variable

```
$input = "Hello everybody [ I want this sub string ]. Hi. How are you?";
```

And a function to get a sub string between to characters

```
function getSubstring($input, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match("~".$start."(.*?)".$end."~", $input, $output);

    return $output[1];
}
```

I am getting output **ello everybody [ I want this sub string ].**   using

```
echo getSubstring($input, 'H', 'H');
```

But no output for

```
echo getSubstring($input, '[', ']');
```

Because '[' and ']' are spacial characters

To get both output how to modify following line

```
preg_match("~".$start."(.*?)".$end."~", $input, $output);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for escaping special characters which are:

> . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

```
$input = "Hello everybody [ I want this sub string ]. Hi. How are you?";
function getSubstring($input, $start, $end)
{

    preg_match("~".preg_quote($start)."(.*?)".preg_quote($end)."~", $input, $output);
    return $output[1];
}
echo getSubstring($input, '[', ']');//I want this sub string
```